# What does the new command on the f4-key do?

Tags: keyboard

I used to have a dashboard icon, which opened the dashboard when clicked on my keyboard.

But now there is another image, which does nothing when clicked.

What is it supposed to do?

How to I fix it?

How do I alternative assign it to dashboard again?

Image: [image]

Also what does the key with an upward arrow and a line do?

And what does the one with a crossed box do?

Image 2: [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to make the launchpad key work as dashboard-key:

- Install [FunctionFlip](http://kevingessner.com/software/functionflip/)
- Open Settings
- Goto Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Mission Control

  - Check Dashboard and set it to f4
- Goto the Keyboard tab and check "Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys"
- Click the back button or "Show all" and open the FunctionFlip settings
- Check **all** the function-keys in "Select keys to flip" **except F4**

  - Repeat this for all the keyboards. If you just want it to work normally also check F4
- Also check start FunctionFlip at login

Answer (score 1):

Caret and Line is Enter, and the crossed box is clear.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Keyboard

Comment: What does clear do?

Comment: give it a try in the calculator application where it will perform the function of the C key.

Answer (score 0):

You need Lion to use the **new** F3 for Mission Control and the **new** F4 for Launchpad.

Comment: I have lion, f4 not working anyway

Comment: disabled in the keyboard shortcut preference setting?

Comment: Nope, and I have found the solution: `rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist`

Comment: @Tyilo Why not post the solution as an answer here? :)

Comment: need 100 repo or wait 8 hour after this question was posted

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>F4</kbd> / <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd> is supposed to toggle Launchpad. If it doesn't do anything, see if Show Launchpad is checked in the Keyboard preference pane:

[image]

It doesn't have to be assigned to any regular shortcut though.